# Generating Excel Export using a link?

Tags: list, excel

Trying to build a 'generate report' link with various options. I would have three links, each with different list filtration criteria. The idea is then that whilst people are on that page, they can click any of the three links, a report will be generated based on the criteria given, and an excel spreadsheet download will pop up on their PC.

So basically near instant excel exports based on specific criteria, which download when a link within a page is clicked.

Any pointers? Thanks.

Comment: Is this for SharePoint? -There's an Export to Excel button in the tab bar on each List View.

Comment: @PaulLeigh I know; and that's exactly what I need - except ideally I'd like to have three links which are pre-defined to do this with different filters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Excel URL Protocol described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms478653.aspx

With it you can create your three links and generate the excels on the fly, example:

```
 http://Server_Name/[sites/][Site_Name/]_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Using=_layouts/query.iqy&List=GUID&View=GUID&CacheControl=1
```

Comment: this helped a huge amount, thanks. I've now got it set up and working exactly as I want, however I'm hitting one problem in particular. Whilst this works perfectly in Internet Explorer, if I try it in Chrome or Safari I get the following error: https://www.dropbox.com/s/nj99eu2ki1isg5b/Screenshot%202013-11-29%2011.52.56.png

Comment: ^ Obviously it's not a *colossal* issue as I can persuade staff to use IE for this site, but it'd be easier if all could use on anything.

Comment: The office integration with other browser do not work very often - least effort is to use IE.

Comment: Yeah, I'll stick a note on  the site to let people know they'll need IE for that feature. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: http://Server_Name/[sites/][Site_Name]/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Using=_layouts/query.iqy&List=GUID&View=GUID&CacheControl=1

Comment: is this working on SP13?

Comment: Yes, it is. And I would be surprised if there is a change for SP2016.

Comment: does Office need to be installed on the machine? I tried using that url but I get a not well formed file

Comment: Yes, its only generating a query file to tell excel how to get the data.