# Add a link to Export a SP list to Excel

Tags: download

I have tried the URL below to export a SharePoint 2013 list to Excel, but it doesn't work for me. I always got an error.

{Site URL}/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Using=_layouts/query.iqy&List={List GUID}&View={View GUID}&CacheControl=1

will you please instruct me how to correct this? in addition, how can I make the download possible using the Chrome? I learnt a tip to add " download target=”_blank”, but I have not idea where to add the element. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The URL seems fine, since I could use the URL to export a list to excel (Tested on Internet Explorer 11.1480). But it seems that the URL will not work on Chrome.

(Older question and answers about similar issue could be found [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/83983/generating-excel-export-using-a-link))

This case is similar to other features such as Open with Explorer (on a Document Library), which works great on IE but is not working on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

This functionality requires Internet Explorer as it is supported by an ActiveX control included with Office.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526(v=office.15).aspx#activex

SpreadSheetLauncher - Owssupp.dll - Used to verify whether Excel is installed for Export to Excel feature.
Internet Explorer versions 8, 9, and 10
If Excel is not installed, an error message states that a list cannot be imported because a compatible spreadsheet application is not installed or is not compatible with the browser.